# (C#) How to convert date formats passed in as a string without using DateTime?

Tags: c#, date

I cannot solve this problem on my own and my professor didn't have time to show me. Not his fault.
I would like to understand as many concepts as possible so I really don't like skipping theory and practice.
Should this problem be solved using DateTime, using Convert/Parse methods or even creating substrings? We didn't even mention DateTime or substrings in class so far so I'm really confused.
Please, if anyone can explain this in a little more detail, or showing some code, I would greatly appreciate it.

**PROBLEM (C#):**

*User enters a date using a keyboard in a form YYYYMMDD, e.g. 20201030 which stands for 30.10.2020. It is required to create a function which will the given date YYYYMMDD convert into a date format DD.MM.YYYY. In case if a user entry contains some letter or if a month is written that is larger than 12 or day that is larger than 31, it is required to display a message: "Wrong type of date entered". It is not necessary to check in detail for the number of days for each month.*

Comment: "I cannot solve this problem on my own" - why not? Give it a try first and show us what you've got, then we can help you get there.

Comment: A hint: you actually have an example input and output: "20201030" should end up as "30.10.2020". Try to figure out how to make that happen

Comment: StackOverflow isn't a code-writing service.  But, considering your problem, what you need to do is write a program that takes a string like `"20201030"`, parses it into three separate numbers (`2020`, `10`, `30`), validates everything and then glues it back together.  The validation will require a table of month lengths and an understanding of leap-year rules (don't forget about the diff between 1900 and 2000).  The parsing step could be done two different ways, either by using integer modulus and division or by using substrings.  The are advantages either way.

Comment: Do you guys know of any good code-writing services lol?

Comment: Given your level, I wouldn't think the teacher expects you to handle things like leap years, or even correct days of each month, but I'm sure you can double-check that with him/her. Consider it a win if you can manage to format the date string after validating the input based on whatever is in that text. @Flydog57 is absolutely right, if this were code for a real application.

Comment: I didn't know that this wasn't allowed here. Sorry.

Comment: @Wixxybyte that's what is called freelancers or consultants, and it ain't free :-)

Comment: Start from *string manipulation*: can you check that string is `8` characters long (`Length`)? Can you extract year, month, day *substrings* (`Substring`)? Can you turn these chunks into *integers* (`int.TryParse`). Finally, you have to validate these `year, month, day` integers with the only possible problem of *leap year*.

Comment: @insane_developer I guess that might be a shot I'll need very soon haha

Comment: @Dmitry though I would point out that the spec doesn't ever say that < 8 chars will be input whereas it does give some examples of bad input that are to be expected.. nor does it mention leap years

Comment: Another way to parse the number is to use `int.TryParse` to parse the entire YYYYMMDD string into an integer.  Then check if it's between, say 19000101 and 21991231 (inclusive). Once you have that, use integer division and modulo operations to get the year/month/day: `var year = dateNum / 1_00_00; var rest = dateNum % 1_00_00; var month = rest / 1_00; var day = rest % 1_00;`. To check the days, create an array of 12 integers: `var daysPerMonth = new[] {31, 28, 31, 30, 31, 30, 31, 31, 30, 31, 30, 31};`, but remember that array indexing starts at 0, not 1.  Finally, leap years.

Comment: @Flydog57 - The exercise clearly states: _It is not necessary to check in detail for the number of days for each month._.  The OP only really needs to check if the month is greater than 12, or if the day is greater than 31.  While that allows for invalid dates, I'm guessing this is an exercise in string parsing, although it would be nice if there was more detail.

Comment: @ChrisDunaway Oh, my bad. I thought that refers to the switch statement. Thank you guys so much for your help. I guess I'm done with the task. Now I just need to study some of these concepts and implement them more in action. This was the first time I used the Parse method and using substrings. I don't even have substrings in my initial college documentation which I find funny. Sorry for the noobish question.

Comment: But, again, you can do it either with sub-strings or with integer arithmetic (integer division and integer modulus). Good luck.  @ChrisDunaway: Yeah, it says not to check the days details, but, if the OP has studied arrays at all, it's a good thing to do.  I remember it as one of the first examples in the original K&R C book (the skinny, pre-Ansi-C edition). And, leap year rules are a good exercise of true/false logic.  If year is divisible by 400, true, else if by 100, false, else if by 4, true, else false.  Package that up in a little `bool IsLeapYear(int yearNum)` function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Dates (in the sense of "a moment in time") don't have a format, so we could reasonably take the specification to turn it into a date format DD.MM.YYYY as "a string where there is a double digit day, double digit month and quad digit year"

We don't need to use date classes either; we can just cut the string up, trial it for conversion to a number (catching the letter bad data entry) and check the number is in range (catching the 12 and 31)

It is further compounded that we don't need to generate a valid date by the statement that it doesn't have to be very involved in checking days per month

As such you can use..

...something like this to get your user input:

```
string input = Console.ReadLine();
```

...something like this to cut your date string up:

```
string monthString = input.Substring(4,2);
```

...something like this to convert it to a number:

```
int monthNum;
bool successMonth = int.TryParse(monthString, out monthNum);
```

...something like this to check if there is a letter in the month or the month is out of range:

```
if(!successMonth || monthNum > 12)
```

...something like this to shape your cut up strings back into a different format if all the checks pass:

```
string result = dayString + "." + monthString + "." + yearString;
```

---

I haven't don't all your homework for you; you're going to have to take these bare bones and build an actual solution out of it ... sit down with a pen and paper first, write out the algorithm (set of steps) then use it as a plan to write the code. Consider transferring your algorithm into comments first then write the code underneath:

```
//print a message asking for user input in YYYYMMDD

//read the user input 

//cut the year out

//cut the month out 

...
```

And so on

Comment: I suggest adding `input.Length == 8` validation; otherwise `input.Substring(4,2);` can well throw unwanted exception

Comment: It's a good point for further development - for the starter I was aiming that this advice be the bare minimum to get something going assuming perfect inputs (or inputs that are imperfect in only the ways specified in the question). @Wixxybyte make note - perhaps get the basic thing working then try putting really bad input in and look at handling that too.

Comment: Thank you so much, @CaiusJard. The only problem is that when I input a letter in a console, it gives me an exception. Month and day numbers are all set, but how can I set a condition so when a letter is typed, it shows me a message like "Wrong data entry."? I only started programming 4 days ago so I hope you can understand my ignorance.

Comment: `if (monthNum > 12 || dayNum > 31)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Wrong data entry.");
            }
            else
            {
                string result = dayString + "." + monthString + "." + yearString + ".";
                Console.WriteLine(result);
            }`

Comment: You also want to check that monthNum and dayNum are greater than 0.

Comment: @Wixxybyte: Are you using `int.TryParse` as shown.  If the parse fails (for example, you enter "ten" instead of "10", then that function will return false instead of true.

Comment: @Flydog57 I just realized that when I input for example 8 letters, the console display the "Wrong data entry." However, when I input more or less character than 8, it gives me an exception unhandled error. I believe @DmitryBychenko was right about this. I should just put `input.length == 8` validation somewhere, but I'm not sure where and how. Also, would that even solve the issue. What if a user entered one letter by mistake and instead of giving me an unhandled exception, the console prompts a message on the screen. Any ideas on how to achieve that?

Comment: The `int.TryParse` function does not throw an exception (on error, it returns  `false`).  Are you using `Convert.ToInt32` or `int.Parse`?  If not, what is your exception (type, message and line of code)

Comment: @Flydog57 I am using `int.TryParse` function. **System.ArgumentOutOfRangeException: 'Index and length must refer to a location within the string.** `string yearString = input.Substring(0, 4);`

Comment: Does the input string have at least 4 characters in it?

Comment: Dimitry recommended to check the input is 8, but it doesn't *solve* the problem as it is only a check. You can check that input ==8, but it doesn't stop you causing an argumentOutOfRange immediately after by saying Substribg(100,999) - ie indexes that don't exist.  It cannot be the case that you get an exception if input contains more than 8 characters because you (should) only be caring about 8 of them (ie substring 0,4 and 4,2 and 6,2)

Comment: Note that substring takes a startindex and a Length, not two indexes, so the day is at index 6, and is 2 characters(for example)